# Configuring Windows Application in RFT

Tags: automated-testing, windows

I Configured a windows application using Application Configuration Tool. Then I did the recording and when I play back the Application is opening fine but the script after that is not running. When I try to debug some times it is identifying and running the script but some times it is not running right after opening the application. It should put the credentials and login to the application. 
If I debug the script and keep pressing <kbd>**Cntrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**F8**</kbd> some times it is running. Some times it is not running. If not debugging it is not running at all after opening the application. Do anyone know why? I inserted Delay also but still the same.

```
        StartApp("Application Name")
        Delay(10000)
        UserEditText().Click(AtPoint(55, 12))
        Delay(10000)
        LogonToApplication().InputChars("UserName")
        PwdEditText().Click(AtPoint(107,7))
        LogonToApplication().InputKeys("Password")
        OKButton().Click()
```

--- In the screenshot I attached. In the Playback the script it is showing is just `UserEditText().Click` not the exact script with the co-ordinates which is `UserEditText().Click(AtPoint(55, 12))`.

Is that a problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a timeout after which RFT typically throws either an Exception dialog (which is can be turned on/off  through preferences)   or  stops the script with the  ObjectNotFound or some other exception  like WindowActivationFailed. I would suggest to have a look at the  RFT preferneces/Options  for various timeout values/delays  in  preferences/options  under Functional Test/Playback .

The playback Monitor does not display the   Coordinates  so that  should not  be causing this issue .
Thanks